# Python3.8.1 installed but the compiler can't find it

Tags: python, python-3.x, homebrew

Python 3.8.1 has been installed, but it still says the version is 2.7.17. How can I actually use 3.8.1?

```
$ brew install python@3.8
Warning: python@3.8 3.8.1 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 3.8.1, run `brew reinstall python@3.8`
$ python --version
Python 2.7.17
```

Comment: What about `python3 --version`?

Comment: it could also be `python38` or `python3.8`, all possible aliases as well

Comment: it is installed but not in the PATH environment variable (or after the path that contains 2.7)

Comment: try `py` into your cmd line see if you get back 3.8 version, else your environment variables maybe messed up

Comment: ```python 3 --version``` returns ```Python 3.8.1```, but the problem is it doesn't seem to be working. ```line 69
    print(col, end="")
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax``` I think this is happening because the complier can't find Python 3.8.1 and we can't use ```end``` in Python2.

Comment: There is no compiler. The shell and the python interpreter are the two relevant entities you are dealing with here.

Comment: Note, `python3` with no space, not `python 3` with a space. If you're getting a syntax error then you will have to show us the code.

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew installs Python 3 under `python3`; it never aliases `python` to Python 3 unless you explicitely ask it: https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python#python-3x-or-python-2x

> The executables are organised as follows so that Python 2 and Python 3
>   can both be installed without conflict:
>
> - `python3` points to Homebrew’s Python 3.x (if installed)
> - `python2` points to Homebrew’s Python 2.7.x (if installed)
> - `python` points to Homebrew’s Python 2.7.x (if installed) otherwise the macOS system Python. Check out `brew info python` if you wish to add Homebrew’s 3.x python to your PATH.

Following `brew info python`’s output, you should be able to get unversioned aliases pointing to Python 3 by adding the following path in your `$PATH`:

```
$(brew --prefix python@3.8)/libexec/bin
```

That is, add the following line in your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`:

```
PATH="$(brew --prefix python@3.8)/libexec/bin:$PATH"
```

Start a new shell, and `python` should be Python 3.8.